# What is the connection between those claims and $s=sup(A)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> 1. $\forall a\in A$ , $a\leq s$
> 2. $\forall a\in A$ $\exists t$, $t<s$ and $a<t$
> 3. $\forall x>s$ there is $a\in A$ such that $s<a<x$
> 4. for all finite subset $B\subseteq A$ , $max(B)\leq s$
> 5. $s$ is the supremum of $A\cup \{s\}$

1) $s=sup(A)\rightarrow$ the claim in 1

2) claim 2 contradicts $s=sup(A)$

3) claim 3 contradicts $s=sup(A)$

4) $s=sup(A)\rightarrow$ the claim in 4

5) there is no connection between claim 5 and $s=sup(A)$

I am not sure about answer 5, I took for example $A=[0,10], s=60$ which show that it can be just an upper bound and not a supermum, is it correct?

Comment: What's $t$?????

Comment: Taking $A = [0, 10]$ doesn't yield $s = 60$. $sup(A) = s \implies sup(A \cup \{s\}) = max(sup(A), sup(\{s\})) = max(s, s) = s$
The reciprocal is not true, though, as you pointed.

Comment: Is (2) meant to be $$\exists t,\forall a\in A, a<t<s$$ or $$\forall a\in A,\exists t, a<t<s\quad ?$$ The first contradicts $s=\sup A$, the second version may or may not hold, depending on $A$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli sorry edited claim 2

Answer (score 1):

There is a connection with 5, but not a great one. 5 is a consequence of $s = \sup {A} $, as are 1 and 4 (1 and 4 are equivalent). 2 and 3 contradict $s = \sup {A} $, but that could be a typo. If you add the phrase "there does not exist a $t $ such that" to 2 and reverse some of the inequalities in 3, then I think 1-5 will add up to a somewhat convoluted characterization of the supremum.